# How to fix multiple subqueries in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a query for an employee table that deals with deductions.  There can be single deductions that happen once a year, or recurring deductions that happen 26 times a year (every other week).
In my query, I need to add the single deduction and total value of the recurring deductions (so 26*fixed_amount).  I add these up and see if they are greater or equal to a specified value.
I am somewhat of a novice when it comes to SQL, so it's possible I'm going about this the wrong way.

I have a query that does subqueries and calculates total_amount.  It is similar to the SQL query I will show - except the subqueries are before the WHERE clause.  In that query, I get a table of all employees and their total_amount deducted.

```
SELECT f.id, f.employeeid, e.lastname last_name
FROM deductions f
LEFT JOIN employees e on e.employeeid = f.employeeid
WHERE e.employeeid = f.employeeid
AND f.year = '2020'
AND EXISTS (
    (SELECT IFNULL(
        (SELECT SUM(f2.amount*26)  FROM deductions f2
        WHERE f2.payment_type = 'recur'
        AND f2.year=2020
        AND f2.employeeid=f.employeeid
        GROUP BY f2.empid) ,0)
    ) recurring,

    (SELECT IFNULL(
        (SELECT SUM(f2.amount)  FROM deductions f2
        WHERE f2.payment_type = 'one'
        AND f2.year=2020
        AND f2.employeeid=f.employeeid
        GROUP BY f2.empid) ,0)
    ) single,

    (SELECT recurring + single ) total_amount >= 100 
);
```

What I'd like for my returned rows are only employees that have a total_amount >= 100.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result. A few rows will go a long way for us to understand what you need.

Comment: When you use `EXISTS()`, you shouldn't be doing any calculations in the `SELECT` list. `EXISTS()` just checks whether the subquery matches any rows, it doesn't use the values that are selected.

Comment: Is there a difference between `f2.employeeid` and `f2.empid`?

Comment: That was a typo.  It should just have been employeeid.

Comment: In the result, do you want one row per deduction, or one row per employee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `EXISTS()`. Use the subqueries as expressions in the `WHERE` clause directly.

It's also possible to do the two calculations in a single subquery.

```
SELECT f.id, f.employeeid, e.lastname last_name
FROM deductions f
LEFT JOIN employees e on e.employeeid = f.employeeid
WHERE f.year = '2020'
AND (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IF(f2.payment_type = 'recur', f2.amount * 26, 0)), 0) +
            IFNULL(SUM(IF(f2.payment_type = 'once', f2.amount, 0)), 0)
    FROM deductions f2
    WHERE f2.year=2020
    AND f2.employeeid=f.employeeid) >= 100
```

Also, you don't need both `ON e.employeeid = f.employeeid` and `WHERE e.employeeid = f.employeeid`. It should only be in the `ON` clause.

And you don't need `GROUP BY` in the subquery, because it's a correlated subquery that's only processing that employee ID.

Comment: Barmar - great explanation.  Your solution works and also taught me a bit more about SQL.  This solves my problem.